# Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I have RabbitMQ running server A and a consumer of the rabbitMQ in server B .I'am using spring-boot rabbitMQ and this is my configuration.

```
  @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, true);
    }

@Bean
public TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(topicExchangeName);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(prefix);
}

@Bean
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory =new CachingConnectionFactory() ;
    connectionFactory.setCacheMode(CachingConnectionFactory.CacheMode.CHANNEL);
    connectionFactory.setHost(host);
    connectionFactory.setPort(port);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(userName);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(password);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("connectionFactory")
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                         MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueueNames(queueName);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(RabbitConsumer receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "consumeMessage");
}
```

but when i deploy and run it , i keep getting this error

```
 2020-03-04 | 07:54:17.344 | container-1 | ERROR | o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer | Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and the error handler threw an exception
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:105) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1378) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1631) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1424) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_242]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1651) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1555) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1478) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1466) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1461) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1410) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: failed to convert serialized Message content
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:114) ~[spring-amqp-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.extractMessage(AbstractAdaptableMessageListener.java:285) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:282) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1552) [spring-rabbit-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not deserialize object
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:95) ~[spring-amqp-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:110) ~[spring-amqp-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7009541904449236102, local class serialVersionUID = 6275967693128102740
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:699) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1940) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1806) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1940) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1806) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2097) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2222) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2342) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2222) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2124) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at org.springframework.amqp.utils.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:92) ~[spring-amqp-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

i have tried making the consumer accept both byte array and string but to no vain.
i'am

it's been 2 days and i'am stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -7009541904449236102, local class serialVersionUID = 6275967693128102740

This simply means that the class serialized on the producer is different to the class on the consumer.

The default `SimpleMessageConverter` uses Java serialization by default (unless the payload is a `byte[]` or `String`.

When using java serialization, the classes must be identical.

Either make sure the classes are in sync, or consider using something like JSON for serialization instead.

Comment: but i'am publishing string with content type "text/plain"

Comment: Well; clearly not:  `SimpleMessageConverter.fromMessage(SimpleMessageConverter.java:110)`  - that line is only invoked if the contentType is `application/x-java-serialized-object`. Edit the question to show your publishing code.

Comment: the publish code is part of the customer , so i can't show . but going through my configuration , realized i was consuming from wrong queue which was publishing a json object. thanks for the tip , it helped a lot